# ListBox still scrolling after handled events

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

**Scenario**:

I have a `ListBox` with a transparent `Grid` over it with some buttons (not in the source).

**Problem**:

If I touch the `Grid`, the `ListBox` under the `Gird` still scrolls, even though I set `e.handled=true` in all manipulation events?

this is the source **MainPage.xaml**: http://pastebin.com/p8XeRzwY

and this is the **MainPage.xaml.cs**:  http://pastebin.com/KFL58VAL

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** 
The Same source in windows phone 7.1 works as expected, so can be a bug of wp8?

Comment: It's preferable to post the code directly here, eventually those links WILL go down. If someone runs into this problem later and can't reference code that gives context to your question & someone's answer, its useless.

Comment: Why do you not want it to scroll? Should you be using a different layout technique? `ItemsControl`?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` on your `ListBox`. That should prevent the scrolling.

Comment: Don't works simple because once you have set IsHitTestVisible to false, how to activate again if not receive hit! :(

Comment: Maybe you can re-enable it from code behind, when you need to scroll again? Is your transparent grid shown all the time or just under certain circumstances?

Comment: Yes, blocking listbox when hit the panel area and unblock when leave it, but the problem is that you forget alway the first hit, if I hit the listbox with my finger I unblock setting IsHitTestVisible, so the first hit don't will not propagate to the control, right?